# error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.

Getting this error while compiling.

[image]